# Calling function to fetch data repeatedly is giving overlapping responses despite trying to use promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, native

I have a function that takes a url and data, gets json from an API, creates an object with data in it and returns it. I'm trying to call this function to get different data with different urls, but the responses are overlapping.

I've tried a bunch of different ways to save the data but the answers all come back the same. Here are some examples of what I've tried.

```
//Get Metals Data
const platListData = getListData(platListURL, this.state.lineChartData, months);
const pallListData = getListData(pallListURL, this.state.lineChartData, months);
const rhodListData = getListData(rhodListURL, this.state.lineChartData, months);

Promise.all([ platListData, pallListData, rhodListData ]).then((responses) => {
  console.log(responses)
    this.setState({
        platListData: responses[0],
        pallListData: responses[1],
        rhodListData: responses[2],
        isLoading: false,
    });
});
```

The code above returns the same response to all 3, which response it gets is random, sometimes its from the first url, sometimes second or third.

```
getAllLists(platListURL, pallListURL, rhodListURL, this.state.lineChartData, months)
  .then(([platListData, pallListData, rhodListData]) => {
    console.log(platListData, pallListData, rhodListData);
  })
```

The code above calls the function below, which tries to fetch them from the main function with all the code that handles the json and creates the object with the data I need.

export function getAllLists(url, url2, url3, data, months){
  return Promise.all([getListData(url, data, months), getListData(url2, data, months), getListData(url3, data, months)])
}

And lastly I've tried the code below:

```
getListData(platListURL, this.state.lineChartData, months)
.then((response) => {
  console.log("response1")
  console.log(response)
  this.setState({
    platListData: response,
  })
}).then(() => {
  getListData(platListURL, this.state.lineChartData, months)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("response2")
    console.log(response)
    this.setState({
      pallListData: response,
      isLoading: false
    })
  })
})
```

I've tried a bunch of other stuff, but they all give the same three responses back, which response is sometimes random too.

Don't know if it makes a difference but I'm calling from the function after importing it:

```
import { getListData, getAllLists, getMonth, getDaysInMonth } from './assets/chartData.js'
```

An example of the overlapping responses I'm talking about can be seen below:

```
               [ { labels: [ 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep' ],
               │ datasets:
               │ [ { data: [ 882, 809, 805, 863, 868, 947 ],
               │ color: [Function: color] } ] },

               │ { labels: [ 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep' ],
               │ datasets:
               │ [ { data: [ 882, 809, 805, 863, 868, 947 ],
               │ color: [Function: color] } ] },

               │ { labels: [ 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep' ],
               │ datasets:
               │ [ { data: [ 882, 809, 805, 863, 868, 947 ],
               └ color: [Function: color] } ] } ]
```

Sorry about the weird format, I copied it from a console log in my cmd.

I don't really know what else to try, I just want them each to get their own responses instead of overlapping or whatever may be happening.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share function definition of `getListData`?

Comment: None of above code will give you random responses, `Promise.all` returns the array of responses in the same order promises are passed, also there's is no way the 2nd option can return random response as you are calling them separately, so the issue does not lie in your code but how these API's are written. Can you share these code also?

Comment: The code is too long to paste so I'll upload an image. For the record calling the function individually gets the proper response. But I need all 3 to load before loading the page. The API/URL isn't the issue.

Code: https://i.imgur.com/aYH3Szc.png

Thanks for helping.

Comment: when you are getting the same responses, are these equal `this.state.lineChartData` passed in the param?

Comment: Yeah, it was just a standard empty data form of the object I needed, but thank you, creating 3 empty ones and sending them in individually fixed it for me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: also objects are passed by reference so you should keep the mutability also, i.e. pass a copy of data or at-least shallow copy as per requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following excerpt and the part I bolded:

The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects. There is no implied ordering in the execution of the array of Promises given. On some computers, they may be executed in parallel, or in some sense concurrently, while on others they may be executed serially. **For this reason, there must be no dependency in any Promise on the order of execution of the Promises.**

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Consider using `Promise.allSettled()`

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled